# Register multiple implementations of generic interface in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I want to register an implementation for my service 
`IQueryService<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>`.

So I have code that looks like this:

```
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IQueryService<,>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(QueryService<,,,>);
```

And I want to create a similar implementation for entities with `string` as primary key, let's call it `QueryServiceString`. Is there a way to write it down so that Castle Windsor will automatically pick up which class it should inject?

```
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IQueryService<,STRING?>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(QueryServiceString<,,>)
```

Comment: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/igenericimplementationmatchingstrategy.md this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partially open generic type `IQueryService<,STRING?>` is invalid syntax.

You can register a factory method and resolve a type based on the generic arguments:

```cs
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(QueryService<,>)));
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(QueryServiceString<>)));

IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IQueryService<,>))
    .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, creationContext) =>
    {
        Type type = null;

        var tEntity = creationContext.GenericArguments[0];
        var tPrimaryKey = creationContext.GenericArguments[1];
        if (tPrimaryKey == typeof(string))
        {
            type = typeof(QueryServiceString<>).MakeGenericType(tEntity);
        }
        else
        {
            type = typeof(QueryService<,>).MakeGenericType(tEntity, tPrimaryKey);
        }

        return kernel.Resolve(type);
    }));
```